# SharePoint Online Search Result not returning DisplayForm from Huge Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-search, list-view-threshold

I am trying to configure the search result in SharePoint Online. 
We have a huge document library, with custom columns to modify the properties on a daily basis. The search is returning only the attachments not the Item DispForm to navigate and modify the properties.

I want to configure the result page to show only Displayform.

Please assist.

Thank you

[image: Library]

[image: ITEM DISPLAY FORM]

Answer (score 0):

By default SharePoint use **Best Bet** display templates for search result. This means, based on the parent content type, SharePoint will bind it to item or document display template. But, in search result, the item display template will point to item display form, while document will point to the document open/download url.

To change the link to document display form, you need to create a custom display template. Read more on [custom display templates here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-display-templates-in-sharepoint-2013/). Instead of using the document path manage property, use a combination of ListUrl and ListItemId to generate the URL manually.